# Website down with 3,000 concurrent user 4Gb Memory Dedicated Server (myIsam - MySQL)

Tags: linux, mysql, godaddy, myisam

Our site has 3,000+ concurrent users when we open our registration on our website. The site was too slow and get the server down sometime, even sub accounts websites are down. Free memory was 400MB.

We upgraded our server to 8Gb for us to have a larger allocated memory. After upgrading our site still encountering server down/ slow site.
What should be the best setting for our my.cnf so that our MySql Server would not give up?

This is currently our setting:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=512M
thread_cache_size=256K
tmp_table_size=1G
max_heap_table_size=1G
open_files_limit=1000
max_connections=3000
interactive_timeout=180
wait_timeout=180
key_buffer_size=400M
slow_query_log = ON
```

And now, this is the `top` result:
[image]

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: You should probably post this on the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). I'm not an expert, but I can see that only 2.8GB of RAM is used, 5.5GB is free, and there is nothing cached in RAM. CPU is only at 11%, so maybe you need more workers, maybe you need high I/O, etc. You really need to do some diagnostics.

Comment: Also `MyISAM` engine provide only table-level locking while `InnoDB` allows row-level locking that is more preferrable.

Comment: @Tim any tips to do that. I would like to know to how.

Comment: Server up 42 mins, mysql TIME+ 2:04. You might need more cores, but I'd start with optimizing your software and database. Using InnoDB instead of MyISAM might be a good start.

Comment: "After upgrading our site" to smaller than most people's desktop computers are. Please. Be realistic. Looks like your mysql config is suboptimal and.... who knows about the software (as in: you may need a lot more power). I suggest getting a pro into it if it is urgent - you should have planned to have a competent admin ready before going live.